# Variable spacing on X axis in the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to have difference spacing on X-Axis . See fig :

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp2RJ.png)

- Image is derived  from the paper "Adapted Deep Embeddings"- Tyler R.Scott et al.

So  for example, in the figure above , the spacing on x axis has been 1 unit for x between(and icluding)  1 and 5 . This is different from spacing between 5 and 10  and so on .

Assume that i have the values for all y , for all integer value of x starting from  x =1  to x=1000.

For illustration : 
If i simply  plot y against the selective values of x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200,30,400,500] using matlplotlib :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(t, test_accuracy_Exp1, 'r') # plotting t, a separately    ##Author's Orginal 
plt.plot(t, test_accuracy_Exp5, 'g') # plotting t, a separately ##Diff_LR_for_Diff_layers_2
plt.show()
```

The graph generated still has the equal spacing on x axis ,  and i get the following :

[image]

So how do i control the spacing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the spacing of the axis for all values, but not for individual value spacing.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the answer , which was pretty simple. 
The author, in the above case has used log scaling (only on x axis).

This can be done using semilogx() function in  matplotlib as follows :

```
plt.semilogx(t, test_accuracy_Exp1, 'r') # plotting t, a separately    
plt.semilogx(t, test_accuracy_Exp5, 'g') # plotting t, a separately 
plt.show()
```

More on semilogx : 
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.semilogx.html